# Unable to pass value from one application to another application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two separate Android applications on different devices. Trying to pass or share the destination address (but in this case we will try a string).

If I run both apps on the same device, it works.  However, if I run one app on a device and the other app in an emulator, the result in App2 is showing either "Hello World" or "No Value" and **not** "We are great!" like it should if it passed or shared correctly.

Any ideas why?

Please see code:

**App1: com.example.sharedpreferences**

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("demostring", "We are great ");
    editor.apply();
  }
}
```

**activity_main (app1)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sharedpreferences"
android:sharedUserId="@string/dev"
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/dev1">
.......
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="dev">com.example</string>
<string name="dev1">example</string>
```

---

**App2: com.example.sharedprefs2**

**activity_main (app2)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="dev">com.example</string>
<string name="dev1">example</string>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sharedprefs2"
android:sharedUserId="@string/dev"
android:sharedUserLabel="@string/dev1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    Context con = null;

    try {
        con = this.createPackageContext("com.example.sharedpreferences", 0);
        SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences("demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String your_data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
        tv.setText(your_data);
        Log.d(TAG, "text passed in = " + your_data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Not data shared", e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what SharedPreferences are and how they work.

They store the data locally on your device only. They're not sharable to other devices in any way.

So you can share them the way you posted between 2 apps on the same device. But in no way does this work if it's across multiple devices.

For that you'll need some backend service. Perhaps take a look at Firebase Database.

Comment: Any suggestions as to what I have to do to get this to work, other than a Content Provider?  I have tried almost everything I can think of.  intents, shared prefs, broadcast receiver .etc..  What type of backend service?  I have Firebase Database already with these apps.  Would a notification carry the value between 2 devices?

Comment: Intents, SharedPrefs, Broadcast receivers, all of them are on-device only. With the Firebase Database you could have two apps listen for changes to the same data, and it would sync them correctly. Then 1 app updates the data, while the other reads it.

Comment: that would work, how would I go about doing this?  I have both apps in one project on Firebase